# How to run SIEMonster OVA in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machines

I am trying to setup SIEMonster in aws it has a minimum system requirement of 8CPU and 32GB Ram. I tried with hyper-v enabled ec2instance with 16cores and 64 GB Ram. i got the below error when starting the appliance in virtual box.

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine vm.

The virtual machine 'vm' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Administrator\VirtualBox VMs\vm\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

Due to the hardware requirements i am not able to open OVA in my local machine and add sudo user, enable DHCP or other configurations required before importing the ova in aws.

(I am a developer and new to server management and aws)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SIEMonster Community Edition OVA was not designed to work in AWS, but rather VMware Workstation or ESXi.
The reason being is that the commercial versions of SIEMonster that run in AWS have many ancillary components , including load balancers for data ingestion, EFS mounts, AutoScaling, Route53, segregated volumes etc.